# JQuery Resize image plugin error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to implement a simple plugin that resize image based on a container.
The problem is , I don't understand why it's not resizing my image when I placed it inside a container

This is the simple plugin demo page i'm trying to replicate

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6983010/wserv/imgLiquid/examples/imgLiquid.html

This is my Code

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/float.css">
<script type = "text/javascript" src ="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src ="https://raw.github.com/karacas/imgLiquid/master/src/js/imgLiquid-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".imgLiquidFill").imgLiquid({fill:true, fadeInTime:500});
    $(".imgLiquidNoFill").imgLiquid({fill:false});
});
</script>


</head>
<body>

<div class="container" >
<img src="Creek.jpg"/></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS

```
.container {height: 440px;  width: 950px; background:#FFFFFF}
```

Comment: Your demo works. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, ok, I thought you are plugin author. Your img tag does not have a class assigned, so when you search $(".imgLiquidFill") jquery returns nothing.

Comment: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9./jquery.min.js Is not found,Include jquery properly

Comment: Did you read my comment?

Comment: Something like this. Also you have not-matched closing div tag right after img tag. Remove it.

Comment: @Tommi I got it fixed , I had to use the imgLiquidNoFill class instead of my container / Thank Tommi for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Image</title>

    <style>
        .container{
            background-color:#f7f7f7;
            border:2px solid #ccc;
            margin:10px;
            display:inline-block;
        }
        .imgLiquid {
            display:block;
            overflow: hidden;
            background:transparent url('http://www.lotienes.com/imagenes/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;
        }
        .imgLiquid img{
            visibility:hidden;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://raw.github.com/karacas/imgLiquid/master/src/js/imgLiquid-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".imgLiquidFill").imgLiquid({
                fill: true,
                fadeInTime:200,
                horizontalAlign: "center",
                verticalAlign: "top"
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>  
    <div class="container">
        <span class="imgLiquidFill imgLiquid" style="width:250px; height:250px;">
            <a href="/media/Woody.jpg"  target="_blank" title="test">
                <img alt="" src="/media/Woody.jpg"/>
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your changing the codes and you forgot to define the `imgLiquidFill` and `imgLiquid` in the class which is very important to make this plugin effective. In modifying the codes make sure you didn't forgot anything. Another thing is you can rename the class but make sure you also rename it in the script to make it the same.

Comment: you make me back here. I really get bored reading the question here.

Comment: Try this new feature, https://envelopebudget.com/accounts/register/. Just try to input a password